# Orthogonal complements really confuse me, I think its the notation?

Tags: orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

For example what do I do here, I know wha to do for part a but then...?

> Let$$W=\operatorname{Span}\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\0\\0\end{array}\right),\,\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\\1\\-1\end{array}\right)\right\}$$
>
> (a) Show $v=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\-1\\1\\0\end{array}\right)\in W^{\perp}$.
>
> (b) Determine a basis for $W^{\perp}$.
>
> (c) Determine a matrix $A$ such that $W$ is the row space of $W$ and $W^{\perp}$ is the null space of $A$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Rishabh. Could you possibly insert the picture here so that it is instantly visible? Also if possible, try to include more of your own thoughts, like what exactly you don't understand. I would also suggest s shorter title...

Comment: apologies, sorta first time here i tried including the photo but they didnt let me. Im looking for a fast comprehensive pattern to follow for questions regarding orthogonal compliments, I know what it is but how to get it?

Comment: For future reference, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is how to write MathJax. Sorry I took so many edits to do it for you: quotation sections are confusing, & we can't preview in the browser (my browser, at least) any more.

Comment: Incidentally, I suspect "$W$ is the row space of $W$", reproduced from your original attached image, may be a misprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be some set of vectors. Then the **0rthogonal complement** of $S$ is denoted by $S^{\perp}$ and is defined as the space of all those vectors in the vector space $V$ such that they are orthogonal to every vector in $S$. So
$$S^{\perp}=\{x \in V\, | \, x \cdot s=0 \,\, \forall s \in S\}.$$

In your question $W$ is a subspace generated by two given vectors (call them) $a,b$. So any vector $w \in W$ can be written as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. This means $w=c_1a+c_2b$ for some $c_1,,c_2 \in \Bbb{R}$ (assuming the field is real numbers).

So if we want to test that the given $v \in W^{\perp}$, then all we have to do is to verify if $v$ is orthogonal to BOTH $a$ and $b$. Because once it is then it will be orthogonal to every $w \in W$. So try testing that.

---

For finding a basis, there are a couple of ways of doing that. Here is a (sort of) standard approach. First find $W^{\perp}$. Let $X=\begin{bmatrix}x &y&z&w\end{bmatrix}^T \in W^{\perp}$, then $X \cdot a=0$ and $X \cdot b=0$ implies
\begin{align*}
x+y&=0\\
y+z-w&=0
\end{align*}
Thus the solution set is
$$W^{\perp}=\left\{z\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+w\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} \, \Big| \, z,w \in \Bbb{R}\right\}.$$
Thus a basis for $W^{\perp}$ is
$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \,\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} \right\}.$$

Comment: @RishabhChatterjee I have added some stuff. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: thanks, it seems I was in the right track